# Jsonp cross browser get request

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp

I have a PHP script `func4.php`:

```php
<?php
    include'includes/connect.php';

    $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `c_clicks`");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $clicks = $row['id'];
    }

    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{\"clicks\":".$clicks."}" . ')';
    mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

and a `getJSON()` to call it:

```js
var security = function(){
    var link = $('link').attr("href");
    $.getJSON("http://www.groupon.com-fit.us/test/func4.php?callback=?",
         function(res) {
             alert('the result is ' +res);
         }
    );
};
```

Everything seems to be working fine except when the alert pops up it says "the result is [object object]

Comment: try alert(res.clicks.length); if it works then you have to loop all data elements

Comment: also if you want to browse object in to javascript console you can use  `console.log('the result is ',res);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at `http://jsfiddle.net/yZ3NP/`

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://www.groupon.com-fit.us/test/func4.php?callback=?",
              function(res){
                  alert('the result is ' +res.clicks);
              });
});
```

Comment: hii @vinothini, can you explain me 
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{\"clicks\":".$clicks."}" . ')';